# visualforce data table displays previous values while using filter?

Tags: filters, datatable

I am using Visualforce data table to display account records.I am also using alphabetical filter to display account records based on the alphabet selected .while doing so  if I press "A" it results in account starting with "A" properly, but if I press b it displays accounts with "a" and "b" and c with "a","b" and "c". What could be the issue?. How to rectify it?

[image]

In Visualforce Page:

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!alphabets}" var="a">
<apex:commandLink value="{!a}"  action="{!Alphabetorder}"  style="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.alpha=a,'font-weight:bold','')}"  >
<apex:param name="alpha" value="{!a}"/>
</apex:commandLink>

&nbsp;|&nbsp;
 </apex:repeat>
```

In controller:

```
 string s1;
   if(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha') == 'All')
       s1='%';
   else
       s1= apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha')+'%';
       system.debug('alphabet ordering'+s1);
```

**And added the s1 in query as name like :s1**

Comment: Is this the view of when you select by the letter 'A', because it is still showing reults for 'B'.

Comment: This is when I selected A first then b.It is showing the value of previously selected 'A' value along with 'B'

Comment: So you are not trying to filter by, but instead you want a multiple sort by on one column? Normally when you do something like this you multi-sort by different columns, not values within the same column.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the filter?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [LIKE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) operator here.

You will be having a query inside a class which is fetching Account records.

The sample code to filter Account will be,

```
String charValue = 'A'; // capture the character clicked by an end user
String inputStr = charValue + '%';
List<Account> accountList = [Select Id , Name, BillingCity from Account where Name LIKE : inputStr];
System.debug('New Account List :: '+accountList);
```

Comment: This is how I am using already

Comment: I have updated the question